# Webplayer GUI Rndering issue pixelated

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I made a game in unity3d, Its graphics looking perfect in unity engine. but when i built it and played in web-player its graphics become pixelated and blurry.
So how can i make it pixel perfect game for web-player?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also happened to me once. But i got the answer after some searching on unity.
this is what you need to do.

Select the texture which becomes pixelated.

-From import settings
Texture type=texture
Filter mode=Trilinear
Slect web as a platform and check yes on override for web
Max size=max
Format=truecolor

and click apply this should and definetly help me.

[Source](http://unity3diy.blogspot.com/2014/06/webplayer-gui-rndering-issue.html)

Comment: I was really in trouble and never checked import settings from inspector . It worked thanks for your answer .

Answer (score 2):

Try to change you image size in photoshop i think you save it in small size.
And always make you graphics in vector so it become pixel free and you always have achance to make a new image from vector.